# Managing model association complexity when testing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, design-patterns, rails-activerecord

On several recent projects I've felt that model associations can get very complex very fast. It feels like testing is way harder than it needs to be because of this complexity. For example, I need to create an instance of model `A` for a test. Many times, it looks something like this (this is taken from the app I'm working on right now):

- Create model A, but model A relies on B.
- Model B relies on model C
- Model C relies on D, E, and F. Specifically, it needs 6 F's to be attached for it to be considered valid.
- Model D, E, and F may have a dependency or two.

Finally, A is created. I am using factories on this application and that helps a bit, but it still feels like too much when I need to satisfy so many validations in order to create a simple model that is not related to any of that.

Stubs might help, but I feel like that requirement represents something wrong with the modelling at it's core.

Are there any patterns designed to help with dependencies like this? One thing I've been thinking about is to make most of the validation conditional based on context. The controllers will save the models in that validation context but that lets my test suite create objects that would otherwise be "invalid" in the live app or full integration test suite. The problem with that is that I feel like it alters my codebase for the sake of testing and I think that is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Does "factories help a bit" mean that you need to do more than `create :a` to create an A and its dependencies, or are you concerned with secondary issues like test speed?

Comment: Test speed mainly. It feels like a bandaid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Like you I'd rather not have test-specific code in my application. I'd also rather have validations in place all the time, because if I didn't who knows what test might construct invalid data and thereby pass when it shouldn't?

But it's better when tests run fast. So:

- I trust you've already made everything in the database a seed that should be, i.e. model instances that don't need to change more often than you deploy.
- If you're using factory_girl, rather than just defining associations and letting factory_girl create them all every time, you could make your factory reuse dependencies:

  ```
  factory :a do
    before :create do |a, _|
      a.b ||= B.first || FactoryGirl.create(:b)
    end
  end
  ```

  (Haven't tested that but I trust the intention is clear.)
- If you need to reuse a B sometimes and make a new one sometimes, obviously you have to write some code sometimes. The most sensible thing to do is probably to create a B in the test and pass it in to the A's that should reuse it and not to the ones that don't.